# prevent updates, deletes and truncates on database table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, crud

I am in the process of creating a sql server 2008 database table for auditing users actions.

Is it possible to create a database table which can only inserted in to - no truncates, deletes or updates allowed on the data in the table. One option I know of is to use a different user with limited rights, but this isnt option for me. So looking at other options?

Comment: If a user with limited rights is not an option, then it is logical to conclude your user has unlimited rights. In this case you can't do anything because the user will be able to undo any of your tricks, delete your triggres, revoke your permissions etc. Otherwise you might want to elaborate a bit on your situation with permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a TRIGGER that fires on UPDATE and DELETE and throws an error:

```
CREATE TRIGGER user_action_update on UserActions FOR UPDATE, DELETE AS
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Cannot modify or delete user actions', 16, 1)
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        RETURN
    END
GO
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164047.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do that is to Write a trigger creation script for the table and set the action to " INSTEAD OF "  which will override the triggering action (unwanted action in your case )  for some other code, or null code.

**INSTEAD OF Property**
Specifies that the DML trigger is executed instead of the triggering SQL statement, therefore, overriding the actions of the triggering statements.

Here is a link in how to Write the SQL statement for the trigger creation:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Good luck

- Adrian